# Setting __proto__ of prototype of a Constructor

Tags: javascript, inheritance, constructor

I am inheriting from a `Base` class to `Derived` class like this :

say `Base is View` and `Derived is ItemVIew`

```
function ItemView(){
View.call(this);
}

ItemView.prototype.__proto__ = View.prototype
```

Can the above be acheived with just

```
Iteview.prototype = new View;
```

Also i have another question

When i set `ItemView.prototype.__proto__ = View.prototype`
,The prototype of `ItemView` is `Function.prototype`
and that means i am setting `Function.prototype.__proto__ = View.prototype`
so all the methods of `View.prototype` are inherited by every other Constructor i define ?

Can i solve it by just `ItemView.__proto__ = View.prototype` ?

Which is the reccomended way of Extending a Base class like View so that ItemView is still a constructor ?

Comment: the _proto of a prototype is an object or it's constructor. you use _proto on instances, .prototype on constructors. it's essentially the same as instance.constructor.prototype.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The object referenced by `ItemView.prototype` is what will be assigned as the underlying prototype of objects created via `new ItemView`. `ItemView.prototype.__proto__` is likely (on implementations that have it) to be `Object.prototype`.

But no, you don't want to do `ItemView.prototype = new View();` -- what if `View` needs arguments? This is a very common error.

Instead, in a pre-ES5 environment:

```
function Temp() {
}
Temp.prototype = View.prototype;
ItemView.prototype = new Temp();
ItemView.prototype.constructor = ItemView;
```

In an ES5 environment:

```
ItemView.prototype = Object.create(View.prototype);
ItemView.prototype.constructor = ItemView;
```

...and continue to do your `View.call(this)` from within `ItemView`.

Comment: What is the need for ItemView.prototype.constructor = View ?

Comment: @RanaDeep: Purely convention. That's how the default `prototype` object on JavaScript functions is set up, so we make sure we do the same thing. It's a bit of an oddity: The [specification says it creates that property](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-13.2) (Step 17), which makes you think it's important; but it doesn't actually *use* that property for anything. (It isn't, for instance, used with `instanceof`.) Mimicking what the engine does by default is really cheap, so I always do.

Comment: @RanaDeep: BTW, you may find my helper script for inheritance hierarchies ([`Lineage`](http://code.google.com/p/lineagejs/)) useful, if not for the script itself, possibly just for [this documentation page](http://code.google.com/p/lineagejs/wiki/ComparisonWithPlainJavaScript) showing using it vs. not using it (e.g., doing the same thing with no helper).

Comment: Thanks,also,If i set ItemView.prototype.__proto__ = View.prototype, since the ItemView.prototype is Function.prototype and that means im setting Function.prototype.__proto__ = View.Prototype ? Does that mean every constructor gets the methods of View.prototype ?

Comment: @RanaDeep: `ItemView.prototype` is an object, not a function. (`ItemView` is a function.) If you set `ItemView.prototype.__proto__`, then on an implementation that lets you do that, all you'd be doing is changing the underlying prototype of that one object.

Comment: Yes ItemView.prototype is an object but isnt that object Function.prototype ? Can u reference something since im unclear about this part

Comment: @RanaDeep: No, that object is just an object. (See those steps I linked above.) The `prototype` property on a function object has nothing to do with the *function's* prototype, which would be (for instance) `ItemView.__proto__` (on implementations that have it). `ItemView.__proto__` will be `Function.prototype` unless you change it (which would be unusual). I don't have much to refer to other than the spec, the `Lineage` code (above), and [a few blog posts I've done](http://blog.niftysnippets.org/search/label/javascript).

Comment: Would you not rather set ItemView's constructor to ItemView? `ItemView.prototype.constructor = ItemView;` In your current code when you have an ItemView instance you would get a View instance when doing: `newItemView = new anItemViewInstance.constructor();` One may expect to get an ItemView instance instead.

Comment: @HMR: Yes indeed, thanks. That was an error in the answer. Fixed now, much appreciated.

Comment: @RanaDeep: See HMR's comment above and the corrected answer (if you were looking at `Lineage`, it already did this correctly).